# Calculate the Radius of convergence of $\sum^\infty_1(x+1)^n\frac{(-2)^n+3^n}{n}$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

I need your help:
Calculate the Radius of convergence of the following:

$$ \sum^\infty_1(x+1)^n\frac{(-2)^n+3^n}{n}$$

Im new to this subject, so I'd appreciate it if you can add explanations to your answers.

Thanks a lot

Comment: This is not an entire series, so what do you call its radius of convergence?.

Comment: what do u mean by saying its not an entire series? 
i call the values of X which for them this series converges.

Comment: An entire series is $\sum\limits_na_nx^n$ for some sequence $(a_n)$. But WP considers the extended notion $\sum\limits_na_n(x-c)^n$ for some $c$ and some sequence $(a_n)$, so I guess this is what you mean. Now, how would you approach $\sum\limits_n((-2)^n+3^n)\frac1nx^n$?

Comment: yeah, it was diffecult to see at first, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the $2^n$ is small compared to the $3^n$,
so it can be ignored.

Second, the $\frac1{n}$ doesn't affect the
radius of convergence, only what happens
at the boundary. So it can be ignored.

Third,
the $(x+1)^n$ only affects the center of the circle
where the function can be evaluated.
It moves the center to $(-1, 0)$,
where $x+1 = 0$.

We are left with,
writing $z$ for $x+1$,
$z^n 3^n = (3z)^n$.

We want $|3z| \le 1$
or $|z| \le 1/3$,
so the radius of convergence is $1/3$
with the circle of this radius
centered at $(-1, 0)$.

Determination of how this function
behaves on this circle
takes more work.

Comment: great! thank you for the very helpfull answer.
now i am stuck trying to figure out what happens on the circle.. 
any strategy advice?

Comment: i think i got it for the circule, using dirichlet and leibniz.. thanks

Comment: yep. thank you for the help !