# Does $\sum_1^\infty\bigr(-\frac{1}{3}\bigl)^n \bigl(\frac{(-2)^n+3^n}{n}\bigr)$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

This a follow-up question about whether or the not the values on the circle of this

Q : [Calculate the Radius of convergence of $\sum^\infty_1(x+1)^n\frac{(-2)^n+3^n}{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/408758/) converges

Mainly I need to check if this one converges:
$$\sum_1^\infty\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^n \ \left(\frac{(-2)^n+3^n}{n}\right)$$

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can readily be split into $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2/3)^n}n+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}n.$$ The left one converges by direct comparison to a geometric series, the right one converges by the alternating series test.